# Bigquery Query: Adding a specific value to previous rows in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to create a add a specific value to rows with null value in case they have something that isn't a null value. It's something difficult to understand, but it could be easier in watching the desired output:

This is my actual table:

```
DATESTAMP______________pressure__________final_date 
2021-02-19T21:19:35_______10.12_____________null
2021-02-19T22:19:35_______11.13_____________null
2021-02-19T23:19:35_______10.43_____________null
2021-02-20T00:19:35_______11.98_____________null
2021-02-20T01:19:35_______10.21_____________null
2021-02-20T01:40:10_______20.21_____________2021-02-20
2021-02-24T23:11:00_______10.42_____________null
2021-02-25T00:11:00_______10.51_____________null
2021-02-25T00:11:00_______20.51_____________2021-02-25
2021-02-28T11:11:12_______10.51_____________null
2021-02-28T12:11:12_______10.52_____________null
```

This is mi desired table after doing the query:

```
DATESTAMP______________pressure__________final_date 
2021-02-19T21:19:35_______10.12_____________2021-02-20
2021-02-19T22:19:35_______11.13_____________2021-02-20
2021-02-19T23:19:35_______10.43_____________2021-02-20
2021-02-20T00:19:35_______11.98_____________2021-02-20
2021-02-20T01:19:35_______10.21_____________2021-02-20
2021-02-20T01:40:10_______20.21_____________2021-02-20
2021-02-24T23:11:00_______10.42_____________2021-02-25
2021-02-25T00:11:00_______10.51_____________2021-02-25
2021-02-25T00:11:00_______20.51_____________2021-02-25
2021-02-28T11:11:12_______10.51_____________null
2021-02-28T12:11:12_______10.52_____________null
```

It doesn't matter if I have to create a new column:
That's my query:

```
SELECT *, IF(final_date is null, LAG(final_date ) OVER (ORDER BY DATESTAMP DESC), final_date ) AS preceding FROM(
SELECT
  * FROM my_table
ORDER BY DATESTAMP ASC)
ORDER BY DATESTAMP ASC
```

And that's the result I received in the before query:

DATESTAMP______________pressure_________final_date_______preceding

2021-02-19T21:19:35_______10.12_____________null_____________null

2021-02-19T22:19:35_______11.13_____________null_____________null

2021-02-19T23:19:35_______10.43_____________null _____________null

2021-02-20T00:19:35_______11.98_____________null _____________null

2021-02-20T01:19:35_______10.21_____________null_____________2021-02-20

2021-02-20T01:40:10_______20.21_____________2021-02-20 ______2021-02-20

2021-02-24T23:11:00_______10.42_____________null_____________null

2021-02-25T00:11:00_______10.51_____________null_____________2021-02-25

2021-02-25T00:11:00_______20.51_____________2021-02-25_______2021-02-25

2021-02-28T11:11:12_______10.51_____________null_____________null

2021-02-28T12:11:12_______10.52_____________null_____________null

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a cumulative minimum:

```
SELECT t.*,
       MIN(final_date) OVER (ORDER BY DATESTAMP DESC) as imputed_final_date
FROM my_table
```